# Using APRegisterExt on an APInvoice DAC

Tags: acumatica

I have this case that the Custom Field is on APRegisterExt DAC.
whereas APInvoice is inherited from APRegister.

Though, I am Doing

`APRegisterExt InvoiceDataExt = InvoiceData.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>();`

it has no error on compile-time, but at run time it gives me error

"getItemExtension Failed"

I just want to set a value programmatically on custom field.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks like everything is defined correctly. Since it is a single value, have you tried AProw.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>().UsrValue = ValueToSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of experiment,

I found the solution

I extended it inside the graph.

after I inserted data on the cache.

`APRegisterExt GetAPExtension = APGraph.Document.Current.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>();`

This trick works for me. Thanks for your suggestion also! :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends a little on what event you are overriding.
For example if you are in the a APTran_RowSelecting event you would pull in the APTranExt like this:

```
public void APTran_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            APTran row = (APTran)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;
            APTranExt ext = sender.GetExtension<APTranExt>(row);
        }
```

Or let's say you are in a PO Order Entry screen and you tap on the POLine_RowSelected event but you need the Inventory item extension value for the inventory item on the line.  You would do something like this:

```
// code to PXSelect the Inventory Item record 
// and assign it to the inventoryitem var.
InventoryItemExt inventoryitemext = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(inventoryitem);
```

One of these patterns should work for you.